# JAX-RS JSON Binding deserialization error when using multiple parameter in POST

Tags: json, post, jax-rs, backend, json-deserialization

I'm trying to develop a Jax-RS POST resource, reported here below:

```
@Path("testJson")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response testJson(Float firstValue, Float secondValue, String thirdValue) {

    LOG.info(" firstValue: " + firstValue);
    LOG.info(" secondValue: " + secondValue);
    LOG.info(" thirdValue: " + thirdValue);

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

However, i get the following error:

```
 RESTEASY002305: Failed executing POST /aliments/testJson: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY008200: JSON Binding deserialization error
```

Searching around, I understood that for a POST method that accepts a JSON, you need to give to it only one parameter, which is in fact the entire JSON message.

My questions are:

1. Why can't I put two or more parameters? Is that because the Json represents the body part of the message and I can have only one body? Can you explain it better to me please?
2. I can create a DTO that contains my parameters and use this DTO as one and only parameter for my POST method, but is this the best practice? Doing so, I will have a DTO for each POST method, which actually acts as a Wrapper.
3. Is there anything I'm missing?

Thank you a lot for your time,
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I put two or more parameters? Is that because the Json represents the body part of the message and I can have only one body? Can you explain it better to me please?

JAX-RS allows for one "entity" parameter. This parameter represents the entire request entity. It is determined to be the entity parameter by not having any annotations<sup>1</sup>. If you want the raw entity, you can use an `InputStream` parameter. If you want a POJO, you can do so. How the conversion works is with the use of `MessageBodyReader`s. The reader will be chosen based on the Content-Type header and the parameter type. The framwork comes with some standard readers for easiliy convertable types. For example String, InputStream, byte[]. The reader will get passed the entity stream and it will need to convert the stream to the parameter type. You can read more about "Entity Providers" [here](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html).

If you want to use a common media type like JSON, there are libraries that handle JSON/POJO conversion, and from that library, a reader can be made. For JSON, a common librabry is Jackson, and there is a Jackson MessageBodyReader that is provided by the Jackson team.

> I can create a DTO that contains my parameters and use this DTO as one and only parameter for my POST method, but is this the best practice? Doing so, I will have a DTO for each POST method, which actually acts as a Wrapper.

Yes, this is very common practice. Get used to it with these type of frameworks.

> Is there anything I'm missing?

I don't know, you tell me.

---

<sub>1. Some special annotation are allowed like `@Valid` for bean validation.</sub>